# Bulk editing privacy guard permissions

Tags: cyanogenmod, privacy

Started playing with the Privacy Guard feature in Cyanogenmod 10.2.1/Android 4.3.1. However, all the applications that were already installed are not retroactively enabled. Ideally I would like to try setting all the permissions to "ask" and see how it goes.

Is there a way to set app permissions in bulk?